# How to Issue and Return a book in Library Managament System

Tags: python, django

**1st Problem** -
What I want is that when a user issue a book the quantity must be decreased by 1 and once there is no book user should not be able to issue the book and this should be handled by bookIssueView(first view)

**2nd Problem** -
I want to return(remove from issued book list) issued books by clicking return and once the book returned the quantity must be increased by 1(I could not handle this also) now  when button clicked it is showing - ConnectionDoesNotExist at /book-return/1/
The connection 'Django For Pro' doesn't exist -  Here is the code written

**Related Views**

```py
def bookIssueView(request, id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
    issue_date = timezone.now()

    quantity = 0
    book_issue = BookIssue.objects.create(
        issue_date=issue_date, book=book, reader=request.user.reader, quantity=quantity
    )
    book = book_issue

    messages.info(request, "Book has been issued.")
    return redirect("book_issue_list"


def bookIssueView(request, id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
    issue_date = timezone.now()

    quantity = 0
    book_issue = BookIssue.objects.create(
        issue_date=issue_date, book=book, reader=request.user.reader, quantity=quantity
    )
    book = book_issue

    messages.info(request, "Book has been issued.")
    return redirect("book_issue_list")
```

Related Models

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY, max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="book_cover/")
    status = models.CharField(choices=BOOK_STATUS, default="Available", max_length=50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)  

class BookIssue(models.Model):
    reader = models.ForeignKey(Reader, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    return_date = models.DateField(default=get_expiry_date)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class BookReturn(models.Model):
    reader = models.ManyToManyField(Reader)
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
    return_date = models.DateField(default=get_expiry_date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For decreasing quantity after creating an object, it's better to override `save()` method for creating and `delete()` method for deleting in your model:

```py
class BookIssue(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: # only for creating not for update:
            self.book.quantity = self.book.quantity - 1
            self.book.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But if you insist to do this in your `views.py`, you can do this:

```py
book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
...
book.quantity = book.quantity - 1
book.save()
```

Comment: [@Amin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10281248/amin)
Thanks for the reply. It worked. But I was not able handle book return part... I have a list of issued books and there is a button for each one to return the book and once the return button clicked the book should be removed from the issued book list and the quantity must be increased since the book is returned... if you can could you show me how to do that part also?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `get_object_or_404` you have to use `DoesNotExist`.

Change this:

```
book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
```

to:

```
try:
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
except Book.DoesNotExist:
    messages.info(request, "Book does not exist.")
    return redirect("book_issue_list")
```